# Attributes on method cause whitespace in javadocs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-8, javadoc

I'm using Java 8 and i have a spring controller that has a method to create a new user:

```
/**
 * Creates a new user in the system
 * 
 * @param username The new user's username
 * @param email The new user's email
 * @param password The new user's password
 * @return the new user
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createUser(
        @RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "email") String email,
        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {
    return "";
}
```

When i generate the javadocs for this, i end up with a ton of whitespace before the parameters.  The generated HTML has lots of whitespace in the `<pre>` tag before the parameters in the list.

If i remove the `@RequestMapping` and `@ResponseBody` attributes from the method, then the javadocs come out as expected.

I've put the resulting generated output from the javadoc tool in the following code snippet.  The first is how it is rendering today, and the second is how it appears correctly with the attributes removed.

```html
<ul class="blockList">
<li class="blockList"><a name="method.detail">
<!--   -->
</a>
<h3>Method Detail</h3>
<a name="createUser-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-">
<!--   -->
</a>
<ul class="blockList">
<li class="blockList">
<h4>createUser</h4>
<pre>@RequestMapping(value="/user/create",
                method=POST)
 @ResponseBody
public&nbsp;java.lang.String&nbsp;createUser(@RequestParam(value="username")
                                                                                                                        java.lang.String&nbsp;username,
                                                                                                                        @RequestParam(value="email")
                                                                                                                        java.lang.String&nbsp;email,
                                                                                                                        @RequestParam(value="password")
                                                                                                                        java.lang.String&nbsp;password)</pre>
<div class="block">Creates a new user in the system</div>
<dl>
<dt><span class="paramLabel">Parameters:</span></dt>
<dd><code>username</code> - The new user's username</dd>
<dd><code>email</code> - The new user's email</dd>
<dd><code>password</code> - The new user's password</dd>
<dt><span class="returnLabel">Returns:</span></dt>
<dd>the new user</dd>
</dl>
</li>
</ul>
<a name="createUserWithoutAttributes-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-">
<!--   -->
</a>
<ul class="blockListLast">
<li class="blockList">
<h4>createUserWithoutAttributes</h4>
<pre>public&nbsp;java.lang.String&nbsp;createUserWithoutAttributes(@RequestParam(value="username")
                                                    java.lang.String&nbsp;username,
                                                    @RequestParam(value="email")
                                                    java.lang.String&nbsp;email,
                                                    @RequestParam(value="password")
                                                    java.lang.String&nbsp;password)</pre>
<div class="block">Creates a new user in the system</div>
<dl>
<dt><span class="paramLabel">Parameters:</span></dt>
<dd><code>username</code> - The new user's username</dd>
<dd><code>email</code> - The new user's email</dd>
<dd><code>password</code> - The new user's password</dd>
<dt><span class="returnLabel">Returns:</span></dt>
<dd>the new user</dd>
</dl>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I don't know where to start digging into this, so i appreciate any input.

javadoc -J-version says:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Javadoc command:

`javadoc -d docs -Xdoclint:none -sourcepath ./MyProject/src -subpackages com -classpath ./spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar./spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: javadoc version and command line?

Comment: ...added to the original question

Comment: I'm getting this too (via gradle's javadoc task). Did you manage to resolve it other than rewriting the generated html files?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is resolved in this JDK bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062647

Since the above metioned bug is resolved in Java 9, upgrading your project to Java 9 should solve your problem.